# Can't pass a javascript function / variable from one case to another

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, parent-child

I'm trying to have the parent window open a child window in one case, and then have that window closed in a different case in the parent window:

```
case "case1": ?>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="javascripts.js></script>
    <script>openWin();</script>
    <?php
        $nextDecision ="
                <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"get\">
                <input type=\"radio\" name=\"choice\" value=\"val1\">message<br>
                <input type=\"submit\">
                </form>";  
                ?>
    break;
case "case2": 
    $nextDecision = "
                <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"get\">
                <input type=\"radio\" id=\"choice\" name=\"choice\" onsubmit=\"closeWin()\" value=\"val2\">message<br>
                <input type=\"submit\">
                </form>";
    break;
```

javascripts.js:

```
var myWindowwin;

function openWin() {
    myWindowwin = window.open("path/file.html","name","width=547,height=480");
}

function closeWin() {
    document.getElementById('choice').value = 'val2';
    myWindowwin.close();
}
```

The child window will open, but not close.

Comment: put the `onsubmit` on the form not the radio button

Comment: @scrappedcola I put it in the form: `<form action=\"index.php\" method=\"get\" value=\"val1\" name=\"form1\" onsubmit=\"closeWin()\">` but nothing changed. THe window opened but didn't close

Comment: Is it on purpose that you're declaring a var called myWindowwin;
but later referring to your child window as myWindow?

Comment: @qternion that was my fault from putting the code onto here. Sorry. Just edited it.

Comment: Some unrelated advice: Use [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for your multiline string. Then you don't need to escape quotes.